# React + Node/Express + Mongo App - Failing to deploy in Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My this app, is working perfectly in local machine with `localhost` . But faililng to deploy in Google App Engine. I have tried quite a few trials with the app.yaml file, but just not able to deploy it successfully. 
**Most probably I am configurating the app.yaml file and the package.json file incorrectly.**

Here's the **[full source code of the project](https://github.com/rohan-paul/deployment-testing-app)**

Here's the crucial part of the [package.json](https://github.com/rohan-paul/deployment-testing-app/blob/master/package.json) file in the in the project root (for the  server).

```
    "scripts": {
        "server": "nodemon index.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
        "start": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
        "fix-code": "prettier-eslint --write 'src/**/*.{js,jsx}' ",
        "fix-styles": "prettier-stylelint --write 'src/**/*.{css,scss}' "
    },
```

And inside my Client directory (which is serving my React client), I have the [package.json for React](https://github.com/rohan-paul/deployment-testing-app/blob/master/client/package.json)

Below is my [app.yaml code](https://github.com/rohan-paul/deployment-testing-app/blob/master/app.yaml) at the root of the project.

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

handlers:
  - url: /api/.*
    script: auto
  - url: /
    static_files: client/build/index.html
    upload: client/build/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: client/build
```

When I finally run `gcloud app deploy` I get below error

```
**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
> server@1.0.0 start /app
> cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev**


> jss@9.8.7 postinstall /app/client/node_modules/jss
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove JSS? You can now support us on open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/jss/donate\u001b[0m')"


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T14_50_44_347Z-debug.log
```

To get the log from gcloud, I run `gcloud app logs tail -s default` and it shows the following

```
2019-03-31 13:28:18 default[20190331t185321]  Express Server running on port 8080
2019-03-31 13:28:19 default[20190331t185321]  Connected to Database (MongoDB)

2019-03-31 13:28:19 default[20190331t185321]  (node:18) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
2019-03-31 13:36:18 default[20190331t185321]  ::ffff:172.17.0.4 - - [Sun, 31 Mar 2019 13:36:18 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
2019-03-31 13:36:18 default[20190331t185321]  ::ffff:172.17.0.4 - - [31/Mar/2019:13:36:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139
2019-03-31 14:49:41 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:49:41 default[20190331t201413]  > server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-31 14:49:41 default[20190331t201413]  > cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev
2019-03-31 14:49:41 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:49:42 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:49:42 default[20190331t201413]  > server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-31 14:49:42 default[20190331t201413]  > cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev
2019-03-31 14:49:42 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:50:42 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:50:42 default[20190331t201413]  > jss@9.8.7 postinstall /app/client/node_modules/jss
2019-03-31 14:50:42 default[20190331t201413]  > node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove JSS? You can now support us on open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/jss/donate\u001b[0m')"
2019-03-31 14:50:42 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR! errno 1
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm run dev`
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR!
2019-03-31 14:50:43 default[20190331t201413]  npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
```

Comment: may be the problem with **opencollective** try to install without that package or use write permission. better to user instance instead of app engine

Comment: No opencollective is not any dependence in the project

Comment: i mean **JSS**,can u share package.json file

Answer (score 1):

A node JS app on Google AppEngine starts with npm run start. You need to keep the 'start' process simple (see documentation). You are changing folders in the 'start' script, but on AppEngine you don't have these folders. Just make sure you 'start' script is simple.